# TYPO3: metatags set by editor

Tags: meta-tags, typo3

Recently I saw a nice extension of Typo3. It is called metatags but I can't find it in the repository. Can someone tell me the extension key?

With that extension it is possible to set keywords, description, robots, revisit, expires, cache-control, pragma and so on. Is it an old extension or a custom one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes the repository search doesn't work (neither from backend nor on typo3.org), so maybe this is the reason you couldn't find it. The extension key is `metatags` an it's here: http://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/metatags/current/

Comment: Thanks for the link! Do you know if it is compatible with Typo 4.5? Since it was last updated on 07.10.2005 ...

Comment: Usually TYPO3 extensions are backward compatible down to version 3.5. (This will not change until 5.0 is released). I guess you are safe to try.